# Subset sum program (Perl)

Tags: perl, subset

The code below is an algorithm that tries to solve the well known subset sum problem. Someone gave me this code, I made a few tweaks and adjustments to it so it would run properly in Perl (the above code will run). Here, "a" is a set of integers, and "b" is the sum, and the program tries finding a subset of "a" that sums to "b", and then prints the result at the end. However when the index of "a" (the number of integers in the set) is relatively large (about 200), the program fails to print all of the subsets of "a" that sum to "b". I know this because I have intentionally chose a subset "a" that sums to an integer "b" I also chose. The program failed to print any subset of "a" (while it was obvious there existed at least one). Believing this was an overflow of some sort, I tried output file directory, and again, checking the files, I found nothing. Any ideas?

---

```
sub Solve
{
  my ($goal, $elements) = @_;

  # For extra speed, you can remove this next line

  my (@results, $RecursiveSolve, $nextValue);

  $RecursiveSolve = sub {
    my ($currentGoal, $included, $index) = @_;

    for ( ; $index < @$elements; ++$index) {
      $nextValue = $elements->[$index];
      # Since elements are sorted, there's no point in trying a
      # non-final element unless it's less than goal/2:
      if ($currentGoal > 2 * $nextValue) {
        $RecursiveSolve->($currentGoal - $nextValue,
                          [ @$included, $nextValue ],
                          $index + 1);
      } else {
        push @results, [ @$included, $nextValue ]
            if $currentGoal == $nextValue;
        return if $nextValue >= $currentGoal;
      }
    } # end for
  }; # end $RecursiveSolve

  $RecursiveSolve->($goal, [], 0);
  undef $RecursiveSolve; # Avoid memory leak from circular reference
  return @results;
} # end Solve


my @results = Solve(b, [a]
);
print "@$_\n" for @results;
```

To give an example, I went to [random.org](https://random.org) and generated a set "a" of 200 random integers from 1 to 2000, took 4 of those random 200 integers, and created a sum "b". Then the code looks like this:

```
sub Solve
{
  my ($goal, $elements) = @_;

  # For extra speed, you can remove this next line

  my (@results, $RecursiveSolve, $nextValue);

  $RecursiveSolve = sub {
    my ($currentGoal, $included, $index) = @_;

    for ( ; $index < @$elements; ++$index) {
      $nextValue = $elements->[$index];
      # Since elements are sorted, there's no point in trying a
      # non-final element unless it's less than goal/2:
      if ($currentGoal > 2 * $nextValue) {
        $RecursiveSolve->($currentGoal - $nextValue,
                          [ @$included, $nextValue ],
                          $index + 1);
      } else {
        push @results, [ @$included, $nextValue ]
            if $currentGoal == $nextValue;
        return if $nextValue >= $currentGoal;
      }
    } # end for
  }; # end $RecursiveSolve

  $RecursiveSolve->($goal, [], 0);
  undef $RecursiveSolve; # Avoid memory leak from circular reference
  return @results;
} # end Solve


my @results = Solve(4022, [34, 63, 83, 86, 88, 90, 95, 105, 107, 115, 120, 132, 140, 145, 146, 149, 154, 165, 167, 173, 175, 197, 199, 250, 267, 289, 291, 306, 328, 341, 344, 347, 349, 355, 370, 379, 389, 390, 393, 409, 430, 454, 474, 475, 476, 483, 488, 518, 522, 544, 554, 571, 582, 587, 591, 606, 614, 615, 639, 647, 663, 673, 679, 703, 742, 754, 765, 791, 803, 816, 819, 829, 841, 848, 852, 858, 861, 865, 870, 872, 873, 903, 909, 914, 915, 918, 931, 934, 937, 947, 970, 974, 983, 986, 1008, 1013, 1018, 1019, 1071, 1074, 1093, 1095, 1097, 1101, 1104, 1115, 1118, 1122, 1143, 1154, 1163, 1165, 1166, 1173, 1174, 1175, 1177, 1182, 1188, 1192, 1195, 1196, 1248, 1259, 1270, 1277, 1285, 1296, 1306, 1312, 1314, 1317, 1319, 1325, 1326, 1333, 1341, 1346, 1355, 1372, 1393, 1394, 1402, 1404, 1407, 1412, 1425, 1426, 1432, 1433, 1436, 1437, 1452, 1454, 1489, 1498, 1504, 1505, 1515, 1521, 1525, 1542, 1556, 1569, 1591, 1592, 1599, 1622, 1624, 1658, 1680, 1685, 1686, 1696, 1725, 1738, 1757, 1768, 1776, 1781, 1782, 1807, 1815, 1820, 1853, 1866, 1868, 1882, 1888, 1891, 1895, 1909, 1911, 1924, 1942, 1946, 1975, 1983, 1988, 1997]
);
print "@$_\n" for @results;
```

There is an obvious subset of "a" whose sum is "b = 4022": [389, 1071, 1248, 1314], however running the code (with the already fixed set "a") prints nothing on the command line, nor anything in the output file. Again, this is likely a memory problem, I'm just not sure how to work around it.

Comment: How is this "likely a memory problem"?

Comment: @melpomene Maybe the subroutine closes over `$RecursiveSolve` and keeps itself alive through that process. But I agree this is not likely IMO. Making `$RecursiveSolve` a global variable could easily prove that.

Comment: There's only one call to `Solve`, so only one instance of `$RecursiveSolve` is ever created (and the circular reference is broken explicitly).

Comment: I can't reproduce the "doesn't print anything" issue because the program takes too long to run. It doesn't terminate even after minutes of running (and it eats gigabytes of memory).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the issue is simply that there are too many combinations to check (which is why it takes so long), and there are too many solutions (so `@results` keeps growing and growing, which you don't see because you only print it at the end).

Comment: It is possible to save some memory by pushing strings instead of arrayrefs into the results array, but that merely delays the problem that your results array grows very very large. Consider printing them out directly.

Comment: "*the program tries finding a subset of "a" that sums to "b"*" - no, the program does an exhaustive search to find *all* subsets of `a` that sum to `b`. It keeps all those found subsets in memory until it exits. Your set has 200 elements, so the number of candidate subsets to check is on the order of 2^200 = 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376. Good luck.

Comment: The most simple suggestion I can think of would be to print when found, without storing. What is the point of @results?

Comment: Crossposted at https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1228495